# curl command get many ` TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):` information

Tags: curl, ssl

When I execute a cmd:

```
curl -vo 1 'https://suapk-auto-us.demo.com/sau-apk/21/08/19/4e3e6e84f68747d1a575b0dd758c7610.apk'  --resolve suapk-auto-us.demo.com:443:1.1.1.1
```

I get many `TLSv1.3(IN) app data, [no content]` information below

```
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
...
```

and there are also some useful information mixed in them:

```
 8 44.2M    8 3671k    0     0   635k      0  0:01:11  0:00:05  0:01:06  723k* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0): 
 9 44.2M    9 4351k    0     0   644k      0  0:01:10  0:00:06  0:01:04  700k* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
 11 44.2M   11 5095k    0     0   652k      0  0:01:09  0:00:07  0:01:02  701k* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
```

my centos version is:

```
CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
```

---

**EDIT-01**

I changed a centos(`CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`) to test, it do not have this problem.